# Accessing servlet class in Message Driven Bean

Tags: java, weblogic, war

We have a web application which is an ear file containing 1 war and 1 MDB jar.
Problem is that I load some properties file in my servlet when first request for servlet comes. These properties I will also need in my MDB. How can I access my Servlet class(inside war) in the EJB jar classes. Is there any way to use my war file as a utility jar.

Application is running on weblogic server.

Answer (score 1):

You don't as a servlet is invoked through a HTTP call. You could hack it by doing an URLConnection to the servlet, but I would rather refactor your code a bit so you can call the initialization code on server startup in stead of by invoking the servlet. A context listener or an EJB init() could already do it.

Answer (score 0):

Extract out your property management into a common, utility JAR that can be accessed from both tiers of your app.

Comment: that seems to be the only option without making much changes to existing code. But I wonder if there is really no way to access a class inside war from outside.

Comment: Not in a way that is useful in your use case. Bundling the shared functionality into a common JAR is the best (and standard) route to take here.